# Null pointer exception for method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list, copy

I am getting a null pointer exception when I call my method to create a new String copy of the passed argument. This method is called from my main.

*Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it so it's not pointing to null?*

It says the error is happening on this line :`front.data = original.charAt(i);`

and if I change the size to -1 it gives the error on this line `back.next = newNode;`

Main (relevant part of method):

```
public class TestLString {
  /** Main method */
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String str1 = "Hello, my name is Alphose!";
      LString lstr1 = new LString(str1);
```

**EDIT: This seemed to work!**

```
   public LString(String original){
  size = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i< original.length(); i++){
     if(original.length() == 0){                              ///changed
        front = new Node();
        front.data = original.charAt(i);
        front.next = back;
        size++;
     } else{
           Node newNode = new Node();
           newNode.data = original.charAt(i);
           Node back = new Node();
           back.next = newNode;
           newNode.next = null;
           back = newNode;
       }
  }
  }
```

my initialized data field(sorry about that). Let me know if I can add anything else.

```
public class LString{


   private Node front = null;  //first val in list
   private Node back;   //last val in list
   private int size = 0;
   private int i;
   private int offset;

   public LString(){
      //construct empty list
      Node LString = new Node();
      front = null;

   }
```

Comment: Where do `front` and `size` come from? I have a feeling we don't have the whole picture

Comment: From your code and description, the most logical explanation is that `front` is null.  But as @KevinBowersox noted, we can't see where `front` is initialized.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace. Helps us debug much, much faster.

Comment: Your logic is not what you're picturing it mentally. Look at your conditional statement.

Answer (score 2):

Where you have

```
if (front == null) { front.data = ...; }
```

That definitely won't work. If `front` is null, then you can't assign a value to its `data` member.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Alternate theory:

You need to initialize front before you use it:

```
front = new Node();
front.data = original.charAt(i);
front.next = back;
size++;
```

**Original Theory**

I'm guessing that instead of

```
if(front == null){
```

you mean

```
if(front != null){
```

because if `front` is null, you can't access its data (`front.data = ...`).